# Orocommerce installation (DB creation isn't performed)

Tags: php, orocommerce

I need your help.
I'm triying to install orocommerce on my ubuntu 20.04 machine.

I followed the instructions given at https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/installation/
I downloaded the code directry from orocommerce (no git, no composer).
Accorging with the isntructions, after the configuration of my parameters.yml file, i executed the script "**sudo php bin/console oro:install --env=prod --timeout=2000 --sample-data=y**" to proceed to install on my environment, but after a few seconds, the installation shows an error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'orocommerce.oro_config' doesn't exist in /var/www/html/orocommerce/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:117
```

Can you help me to undertstand why if i'm trying to install from scratch it asks for an existing table?

My parameter's file

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 'localhost'
    database_port: '3306'
    database_name: 'orocommerce'
    database_user: 'Intcomex'
    database_password: 'Intcomex'
    database_server_version: '10.3.34'
    database_driver_options: {  }
    mailer_dsn: ''
    websocket_bind_address: 0.0.0.0
    websocket_bind_port: 8080
    websocket_frontend_host: '*'
    websocket_frontend_port: 8080
    websocket_frontend_path: ''
    websocket_backend_host: '*'
    websocket_backend_port: 8080
    websocket_backend_path: ''
    websocket_backend_transport: tcp
    websocket_backend_ssl_context_options: {  }
    web_backend_prefix: /admin
    session_handler: session.handler.native_file
    secret: 'Intcomex'
    installed: false 
    message_queue_transport: dbal
    message_queue_transport_config: null
    enable_price_sharding: '0'
    deployment_type: null
    liip_imagine.jpegoptim.binary: null
    liip_imagine.pngquant.binary: null
    env(ORO_DB_HOST): 127.0.0.1
    env(ORO_DB_PORT): 3306
    env(ORO_DB_NAME): orocrm
    env(ORO_DB_USER): Intcomex
    env(ORO_DB_PASSWORD): Intcomex
    env(ORO_DB_VERSION): null
    env(ORO_MAILER_DSN): 'native://default'
    env(ORO_SECRET): ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
    env(ORO_ENABLE_PRICE_SHARDING): '0'
```

Part of the stack trace after install command execution

```
Installing Oro Application.

Check system requirements

In NodeJsVersionChecker.php line 13:

  Oro\Bundle\AssetBundle\NodeJsVersionChecker::satisfies(): Argument #1 ($nodeJsExecutable) must be of type string, null given, called
   in /var/www/html/orocommerce/vendor/oro/platform/src/Oro/Bundle/InstallerBundle/Provider/PlatformRequirementsProvider.php on line 5
  11


oro:check-requirements

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'orocommerce.oro_config' doesn't exist in /var/www/html/orocommerce/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:117
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/orocommerce/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php(117): PDOStatement->execute()
#1 /var/www/html/orocommerce/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(1303): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement->execute()
......
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you haven't installed NodeJS which is required for OroCommerce.
There is an instruction on the local environment setup for ubuntu that you can follow to meet all the system requirements before the installation:
https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/dev-environment/docker-and-symfony/ubuntu/

After installing all the additional software, make sure you clear the cache before retrying the installation. You can do it by running `rm -rf var/cache/*` command in the application root directory

Answer (score 0):

For some reason parameters.yml is parsed incorrectly. Use these lines instead:

```
database_host: '%env(ORO_DB_HOST)%'
database_port: '%env(ORO_DB_PORT)%'
database_name: '%env(ORO_DB_NAME)%'
database_user: '%env(ORO_DB_USER)%'
database_password: '%env(ORO_DB_PASSWORD)%'
database_server_version: '%env(ORO_DB_VERSION)%'

env(ORO_DB_HOST): "localhost"
env(ORO_DB_PORT): "3306"
env(ORO_DB_NAME): orocommerce
env(ORO_DB_USER): Intcomex
env(ORO_DB_PASSWORD): "Intcomex"
env(ORO_DB_VERSION): "10.3.34"
```